# Overflow Exception - Cant see the reason

Tags: vb.net, exception, timer, overflow

I have a simply function that compares two colors and which is called very often per second. So after 20 seconds there always comes and overflow Exception. But i dont know why. What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
Public Function compareColor(color1 As Color, color2 As Color, range As Integer) As Boolean
    If color1.R - color2.R > range OrElse color2.R - color1.R > range Then
        Return False
    End If
    If color1.G - color2.G > range OrElse color2.G - color1.G > range Then
        Return False
    End If
    If color1.B - color2.B > range OrElse color2.B - color1.B > range Then
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you'd have to show what's CALLING this function.

Comment: You probably get that exceptions because A, R, G, B are of type Byte. A Byte has the value Range between 0 and 255. If now color2.R > color1.R you  have a result of your subtraction which is smaller than 0. That results in an overflow exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasVoß, that was the problem.